# Automatically determining whether particular product version is vulnerable?

Tags: vulnerability, api

I'm building a system that contains a lot of data about different versions of various networking software (client software, servers, etc) in a human-readable format. Is there an API that I could query like "Are there any unauthenticated RCEs for Microsoft Exchange 2003" and it would return me with a yes/no answer?

Comment: Are you also considering that vulnerable product may have patches installed making it not vulnerable to specific issue?

Comment: Regarding patches: The circ.lu cve-search mentioned by @daniel-ruf also returns information about the vulnerable configurations: `"vulnerable_configuration": [3]
0:  "cpe:2.3:a:microsoft:exchange_server:2013:cumulative_update_8"`

Comment: @K.P.: it would be perfect to know if the version information lets me determine that; perhaps yes/no/maybe would be a better set.

Answer (score 2):

[cvedetails.com](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-feeds-form.php) offer API access, however I couldn't find any official documentation except for the names of the query parameters. Entries in the database can be filtered for example by vendor, product or vulnerability type.

To get all entries for vendor "Microsoft":

`GET http://www.cvedetails.com/json-feed.php?vendor_id=26`

To get all entries for product "Exchange Server" & vulnerability "Code Execution":

`GET http://www.cvedetails.com/json-feed.php?product_id=194&opec=1`

Comment: This might be also helpful. https://www.circl.lu/services/cve-search/

Comment: We can get data for a specific version from NVD by nist.gov: https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search-results?adv_search=true&cves=on&cpe_vendor=cpe%3a%2f%3amicrosoft&cpe_product=cpe%3a%2f%3amicrosoft%3aexchange_server&cve_id=

Comment: nessus? google nessus api